# Distance Between 2 Coordinates

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms, coordinates, distance

Using the query below in SQL, I am trying to get the distance between the source and target coordinates:

```
DECLARE @source geography = 'POINT(42.3629 -121.3897)'
DECLARE @target geography = 'POINT(47.2921 -111.469)'
SELECT @source.STDistance(@target)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 55 A .NET Framework error occurred
> during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography": 
> System.FormatException: 24201: 
> Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees.
```

The error is stating that my latitude values are out of range, but the 42 and 47 values are well within. This code works whenever the longitude is reduced to something within the specified latitude range.

Where is the incorrect conversion happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry) format used to represent Geography values uses `(X Y)` coordinate order, which is typically mapped to `(longitude latitude)`. MS SQL uses this order too, see example of this format usage here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/spatial-types-geography?view=sql-server-ver15

So you have lat/lng order swapped, use  `'POINT(-121.3897 42.3629)'` instead.